# Kommasetzung in einem komplizierten Relativsatz

Tags: punctuation, comma

Wie hat die Kommasetzung für den folgenden Satz richtig auszusehen?

> Der Projektordner bietet die Möglichkeit, darin Dateien, die Variablen enthalten, abzulegen, um deren Inhalte auch nach dem Neustart des Programms, des Plugins oder der Komponente beizubehalten.

Es sind meiner Meinung nach zu viele, aber welche kann man tatsächlich weglassen und welche braucht man unbedingt?

---

> [Traduction] How should the commas be
>   positioned in the following sentence?
>
> > Der Projektordner bietet die Möglichkeit, darin Dateien, die
> >     Variablen enthalten, abzulegen, um
> >     deren Inhalte auch nach dem Neustart
> >     des Programms, des Plugins oder der
> >     Komponente beizubehalten.
>
> In my opinion there are too many commas,
>   but which ones can be removed and which
>   ones are absolutely needed?

Comment: Wenn man unbedingt einen Satz ohne Kommas haben möchte, kann man auch schreiben: `Der Projektordner bietet die Möglichkeit zur Ablage von variablenenthaltenden Dateien zum Zwecke der Beibehaltung ihrer Inhalte auch nach dem Neustart des Programs oder des Plugins oder der Komponente.` Nur mit mehreren Sätzen ist es wohl verständlicher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die deutsche Grammatik verleitet dazu, lange Schachtelsätze zu bilden. Dies ist aber dann kein guter Stil, wenn das Verständnis einer Aussage leidet.

Besser wäre es, den Text so zu vereinfachen, dass möglichst wenige Kommas nötig werden. Ich würde das Beispiel also wie folgt formulieren:

> In einem Projektordner werden  Dateien gespeichert, die Variablen enthalten. Dadurch sind sie auch noch nach einem Neustart des Programms, eines Plugins oder einer Komponente verfügbar.

Comment: Etwas schöner: In einem Projektordner werden Dateien gespeichert, die Variablen enthalten.

Comment: @toscho: Das Schöne ist, dass es immer noch schöner geht. :)

Comment: Klar, den Passiv nähme ich noch heraus, und »Dateien mit Variablen« finde ich auch besser. Aber das lenkte von der Frage ab.

Answer (score 5):

Wenn man die Wortordnung halten will, sind die Kommas alle notwendig, als sie grenzen Teilsätzen, außer das letzte, das die Komponenten einer Liste abtrennt.

Comment: Richtig. Zumindest teilweise. Sie sind zwar alle notwendig, aber die Erklärung ist nicht ganz korrekt. Das erste Komma leitet einen erweiterten Infinitiv ein. Das 2. und 3. umrahmen einen Relativsatz, das 4. leitet einen Nebensatz ein und das 5. und letzte wird für die Aufzählung benötigt.

Comment: @Martin: Es sieht aus, wie ich zu viel generalisieren wollte. Danke für die Abklärung.

Comment: @Martin: Ich nütze jetzt den Wort _Teilsatz_, um den erweiterten Infinitiv, den Relativsatz und den Nebensatz in ein Wort zu bezeichnen.

Answer (score 4):

Vielleicht ist es in diesem Zusammenhang sinnvoll, die einzelnen Fälle, in denen ein Nebensatz vorhanden ist, aufzuzeigen. Denn davon gibt es überraschend viele:

- Subjektsätze

  - Wie das geht, **frage** ich mich.
  - Was geschehen war, **wollte** er wissen.
- Objektsätze

  - Ich denke, **dass** ich es verstanden habe.
  - Ich frage mich, **ob** es schwierig ist.
- Adverbialsätze (auch Verhältnissätze)

  - Da es dunkel war, schaltete ich das Licht ein

    ([viele Formen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbialsatz))
- Attributsätze

  - Die **Dinge, die** ich sah, waren nur **die, die** man mir zeigte.

Es gibt zudem eine Menge Sonderfälle, die in keine dieser Kategorien passen:

- Da ging er fort, was mich erleichterte.

Andererseits sieht man viele Kommata häufig in komplizierten Schachtelsätzen, wo sie nichts verloren haben:

- Der große, grüne Troll, der unter der Brücke saß, die über den Fluss führte, der in das Meer mündete.

Man kann diese Fälle gut daran erkennen, dass die einzelnen Nebensätze schnell den kontextuellen Bezug zueinander verlieren. Ändert sich im selben Satz das "Thema" sehr stark (vgl. Troll → Meer), so kann man von einem Schachtelsatz ausgehen. Diese sind nicht generell falsch (wie z. B. verschachtelte Klammern), werden aber (heutzutage) eher gemieden.

In deinem Beispiel gibt es nur wenige Möglichkeiten, den Satzbau zu verbessern. Hier muss man vor allem zwischen der Nebensatzbildung und der Auflistung unterscheiden.

> Ich kann laufen, fahren, fliegen oder schwimmen.

Die ersten vier Segmente sind Nebensätze und korrekt getrennt. Im zweiten Teil gibt es eine Liste der Form "1, 2 und 3". Drei Nebensätze zu verschachteln, ist zwar nicht besonders elegant, aber durchaus erlaubt. Eine weniger komplizierte Ausdrucksweise, mit nur einem Nebensatz, wäre zum Beispiel:

> Im Projektordner können Dateien abgelegt werden, die Variablen enthalten. So kann man deren Inhalte auch nach einem Neustart des Programms, des Plug-ins oder der Komponente beibehalten.

Answer (score 1):

Meiner Meinung nach sollte es folgendermaßen aussehen:

> Der Projektordner bietet die Möglichkeit, Dateien, die Variablen enthalten, darin abzulegen, um deren Inhalte auch nach dem Neustart des Programms, des Plugins oder der Komponente beizubehalten.

Wobei ich *beizubehalten* durch *zur Verfügung zu stellen* ersetzen würde.